# azure web api throttle without aure API management

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, throttling

We developed some web api and deployed to azure. Now we are in the process of implementing some rate limitation strategy.

We looked into Azure API Management, but the price tag is just bit too high at the moment. So are there any alternatives? As azure web app has multiple instances, the old method (`HttpRuntime.Cache` or `ConcurrentDictionary`) can't help now.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pattern recommendations at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/throttling but the patterns suggested aren't to the same degree as what API Management offers with setting policies. I would take a closer look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/queue-based-load-leveling as it provides the closest I think to throttling requests.